# Empty Chart for vbar in Bokeh

Tags: python, csv, bokeh

I'm very new to Data Visualisation with Bokeh and have been trying some charts with different glyphs.

I wanted to plot a vbar graph depicting Indian weather in Jan (b/w 1901 - 2017) with data from a csv file. I've seen that the chart turns out empty if I provide categorical data without specifying an x_range. Tried fixing that too.

Needless to say, I got 'Unrecognised Range Input' as an error and checked out a few answers which said that the values had to be strings, which I tried, but to no avail. I still see a very empty chart.

Can someone please help me out with this and explain to me where I've gone wrong?

The CSV file I've been using: https://www.kaggle.com/mahendran1/weather-data-in-india-from-1901-to-2017

What I see as an output: [An empty chart, with no errors in the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqLjM.png)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, curdoc
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("ind_weather.csv")

x = df["YEAR"].astype(str)
y = df["JAN"]

f = figure(x_range = x, plot_width = 500, plot_height = 500, tools = 'pan')
curdoc().theme = "light_minimal"

f.title.text = "Indian Weather in January"
f.title.text_font_size = "20px"
f.title.text_color = "Gray"
f.xaxis.axis_label = "Year"
f.yaxis.axis_label = "Temperature (°C)"

f.vbar(x, y, width = 2, color = "#480ca8")
output_file("weather.html")
show(f)
```

Comment: It's really not possible to speculate without knowing what is in the data. The list of factors for `x_range` needs ot be unique, is that the case? Are there any errors reported in the browser JS console?

Comment: No errors. I've edited the question to include an image of what I see. On excluding .astype(str) from x, I get  `ValueError: Unrecognised range input: '[1901 1902 .... 2017]'`

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out!
I had to equate y's value to top in the `f.vbar()`

```
f.vbar(x, top = y, width = 0.3, color = "#480ca8")
```

Also noticed that the chart looked pretty chaotic with 100 years on the x-axis and decided to scale it down to data for every 10 years.

The entire code looks like this now:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, curdoc, output_notebook
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("ind_weather.csv")

# x = df["YEAR"].astype(str)
x = []

for i in range(len(df['YEAR'])):
    if i % 10 == 9:
        x.append(str(df['YEAR'][i]))
y = df["JAN"]


f = figure(x_range = x, plot_width = 500, plot_height = 500, tools = 'pan', sizing_mode = "stretch_both" )
curdoc().theme = "light_minimal"

f.title.text = "Indian Weather in January"
f.title.text_font_size = "20px"
f.title.text_color = "Gray"
f.xaxis.axis_label = "Year"
f.yaxis.axis_label = "Temperature (°C)"

f.vbar(x, top = y, width = 0.3, color = "#480ca8")
output_file("weather.html")
show(f)
```